# how to break this line in multiple lines?

Tags: php, indentation

This line with html inside php is too long and makes it hard to read, is there an elegant way to break this into multiple lines?

```
<a class="icon-button" href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>"><span><?php echo $term->name; ?></span><svg class="eco-sprite icon icon--go" role="img"><use xlink:href="#shape-ButtonDetailBold"></use></svg></a>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  HTML is extremely forgiving; you can put as many line breaks in the HTML as you want.

Comment: Do you to break in a specific tag?

Comment: you need to post what generated that in the first place if it was dynamically generated.

Comment: For `elegant way` hit `Enter` when the cursor is on a right place. Mostly after `>`.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Now *"THAT"* would be way too easy *lol!* wow, who would've thought?

Comment: @Fred -ii- I always try not to be rude here, but i cant hold it: sometimes i must be ironic :-)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I know and I didn't think your comment was rude in any way; I'd call that a worthy answer (in its own right; short but sweet), if you ask me. But... I smell dynamically-generated (Spidey sense tingle); which I asked and got no response. Another one of those "silent" types.

Comment: @Fred -ii- english is not my mother-tongue so often i dont know how rude it may is what i wrote here.  And irony lives always in the context .-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this you mean...

```
<?php
  . . .
?>
<a class="icon-button" href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>">
    <span><?php echo $term->name; ?></span>
    <svg class="eco-sprite icon icon--go" role="img">
        <use xlink:href="#shape-ButtonDetailBold"></use>
    </svg>
</a>
<?php
 . . .
?>
```

Comment: That would be too easy.

Comment: I am always hopeful of some "LHF"

Comment: Maybe their code is dynamically generated; to which I placed [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186349/how-to-break-this-line-in-multiple-lines#comment73445793_43186349) under the question. Could be anybody's ballgame.

Answer (score 1):

Just indent your HTML:

```
<a class="icon-button" href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>">
    <span><?php echo $term->name; ?></span>
    <svg class="eco-sprite icon icon--go" role="img">
        <use xlink:href="#shape-ButtonDetailBold"></use>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="icon-button" href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>">
    <span>
        <?php echo $term->name; ?>
    </span>
    <svg class="eco-sprite icon icon--go" role="img">
        <use xlink:href="#shape-ButtonDetailBold"></use>
    </svg>
</a>
```